# Passing a URL as a parameter to Node/Express app

Tags: node.js, express

I have a simple Node/Express route, as follows:

```
var app = express();

app.get('gettags/:page', function(request,response)
{
    var thePage = request.params.page;
    ...
    ...
}
```

The problem I'm having is that if I pass a URL as the parameter, I get a "Cannot GET" error. So, if I call this like:

```
http://www.mynodeapp.com/gettags/http://www.someurl.com/?withquery=something
```

I get the "Cannot GET" error. It's been a couple years since I've used Node, so I am probably forgetting something very basic. But I can't get past this, and Googling this issue hasn't turned up anything useful.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your node code looks fine but for this to work you'll need to URI encode your argument:

```
var url = 'http://www.mynodeapp.com/gettags/' + encodeURIComponent('http://www.someurl.com/?withquery=something')

//becomes: http://www.mynodeapp.com/gettags/http%3A%2F%2Fwww.someurl.com%2F%3Fwithquery%3Dsomething
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent

Comment: Ah, quite so. Thank you for that reminder. However, encoding the parameter still yields this "Cannot GET" error. If I pass something other than a URL, no error is thrown. Just a URL does - but that's what I need to be passing. I am perplexed by this. Thank you for your time!

Comment: You need to encode the URI in your *HTTP request*, not in one node.js side.

Comment: Note that express' `/foo/:bar` parameter mechanism splits the URI path by `/` characters. You'll notice that if you try `http://www.mynodeapp.com/gettags/foo/bar` you'll get the same "Cannot GET" error.

Comment: Also you don't _have_ to use the express params syntax, you could do this `app.get('/gettags/*', ...)`, use your unencoded URI as is, and parse `req.originalUrl` yourself, but this is much ickier if you need to add any additional path or query parameters in your request. Simply URI encoding the request parameter is a much simpler option.

Comment: Andrew, yes - i did encode it at the requesting end, not at the Node side. But your "req.originalURL" is actually a better solution because all I need to do is extract the URL as passed and then send it along to another Node module for processing. So this works. Thanks again for your time - appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

The Problem in your code is

> / 's of http://www.someurl.com

so to overcome this use url encoding functions in node such as

```
encodeURIComponent("Your url goes here")
```